# Easy APNS message status set to delivered, but not recieved on devices

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

Easy APNS message status set to delivered, but not recieved on devices
When using EasyAPNS, every message gets through the system fine. When the messages are sent out, the status is set to delivered, but the devices never actually recieve the message.

The code worked perfectly in developer code. but since switching to release mode (the app is live in the app-store) none of the devices actually receives messages that are sent out.

Comment: This is probably because the servers are overloaded. Unfortunately, receiving a push notification is not guaranteed, so you're at the hands of apple to send it through.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but I have tried this a lot of times. And somehow push notifications from other apps are received on the iphones I would like to send messages too.

Comment: Are your certificates setup properly? Are the devices running production or testing versions of the app?

Comment: certificates are set properly and the devices are running production version of the app.